# Load only imagens resized in custom page

Tags: images

I have a custom page called "produtos", and i have created a php file for showing the image in frontpage, but i desire to load only resized images, not raw image rezised.

My code is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page Produtos
 */
get_header();

get_template_part( 'partials/title_box' );

if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'show_breadcrumbs', true ) != 'no' ) {
    get_template_part( 'partials/breadcrumbs' );
}
?>

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'page' );
    }
    get_template_part( 'partials/paginate' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
}
?>

<?php
    $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'produto',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query'         => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'wpcf-tipo',
                        'value'   => ((isset($_GET['tipo']) && ($_GET['tipo']=='menina' || $_GET['tipo']=='menino'))?$_GET['tipo']:array('menino', 'menina')),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'meta_key' => 'wpcf-peso',
                'order'     => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<h3>Filtrar:</h3>
<ul id="products-filter">
    <li class="tudo">
        <a href="/produtos">TODOS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="meninas">
        <a href="/produtos?tipo=menina">MENINAS</a>
    </li>   
    <li class="meninos">
        <a href="/produtos?tipo=menino">MENINOS</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <div class="row" id="products">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 product" alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>">
                <div class="change">
                    <i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php if(types_render_field('lancamento')=="Sim"): ?>
                    <div class="new <?php echo strtolower(types_render_field('tipo')) ?>">
                        <h1>Lançamento</h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="img top">
                        <img alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" src="<?php echo types_render_field("logo", array("width"=>"200","height"=>"200", "raw" => "true")); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img botton">
                        <img alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" src="<?php echo types_render_field("miniatura", array("size"=>"medium", "raw" => "true")); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#products .product .change").click(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).next("a").children(".img.top").toggleClass("noopacity");
    });    
</script>
```

In line 71:

`<div class="img top">`

and in 74:

```
<div class="img botton">
```

The code for display miniature images is inserted. And none of my div codes worked....

```
<img alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" src="<?php echo types_render_field("logo", array("width"=>"200","height"=>"200", "raw" => "true")); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
<img alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" src="<?php echo types_render_field("miniatura", array("size"=>"medium", "raw" => "true")); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
```

But loads the raw image, in original size, not the custom size, as you can see in screenshot:

[image]

I need an assistance, thanks.

Comment: **types_render_field** is not a wordpress function. Do you use a plugin or framework?

Comment: yes, a toolset plugin https://toolset.com/documentation/customizing-sites-using-php/functions/#image . but this only render the fields in frontpage. i need to  load or get the image custom size from wp-uploads/content